# How to solve this loop problem in python flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I try to loop through every article and show it in web page but this is what happens..

My python code:

```
@app.route('/scrapper')
def scrapper():

    response = requests.get('http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=api-key')

    data = response.json() 
    articles = data['articles'] 

    for i in range(len(articles)):
        myarticles = articles[i]

    return render_template('news.html', myarticles=myarticles)
```

And this is how it looks like in html:

```
<body>
{% for info in myarticles %}
    <h2>Title: {{myarticles.title}}  </h2>
    <p>Author: {{myarticles.author}}  </p>
    <p>Url: {{myarticles.url}}  </p>
    <p>Content: {{myarticles.content}} </p>
    <p>Date: {{myarticles.publishedAt}} </p>
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

This returns only one article but many times, as in [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9iJ2.png).
This is my very first project like that so please, be forgiving.

EDIT:
I deleted loop and passed like you said. But now i got nothing, just empty page
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1xC7.png).

Comment: remove the loop in /scrapper and pass in myarticles=articles. What happens now

Comment: side note to the pair of you; "scrapper" is slang for someone who likes to fight in English, usually in a pub. You mean "scraper".

Comment: I mean what ever the OP wrote, and not inferring what he intends with the name of his script since I cannot understand his reasoning nor does it relate to the question.

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this:

```
for i in range(len(articles)):
    myarticles = articles[i]
```

myarticles will always point to the last article inside your list articles.

Since in your template you're already looping over the articles, just pass in articles.

```
return render_template('news.html', myarticles=articles)
```

Forgot to also mention, you need to actually use the looped article:

```
<body>
{% for info in myarticles %}
    <h2>Title: {{myarticles.title}}  </h2>
    <p>Author: {{myarticles.author}}  </p>
    <p>Url: {{myarticles.url}}  </p>
    <p>Content: {{myarticles.content}} </p>
    <p>Date: {{myarticles.publishedAt}} </p>
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

This is wrong because you're not using info, which has the data for each individual article.

You need to change it to:

```
<body>
{% for info in myarticles %}
    <h2>Title: {{info.title}}  </h2>
    <p>Author: {{info.author}}  </p>
    <p>Url: {{info.url}}  </p>
    <p>Content: {{info.content}} </p>
    <p>Date: {{info.publishedAt}} </p>
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

Comment: To be honest i dont really know what should i change now. Maybe because its of the barrier language and i cant fully understand you. Could you show me edited code?

Comment: I showed you the code. return render_template('news.html', myarticles=articles)

Comment: Oh my god, what a shame... I have to go sleep... Thank you so much man! You're my savior!

Comment: It happens all the time @KlaudiuszBednarski, we all make silly mistakes, glad to have helped